# Proof by reduction and Turing machines

Tags: turing-machines, reductions, undecidability, proof-techniques, halting-problem

This is a practice question I have, but I can't wrap my head around it.
.............
Let L = {M | M is a TM that halts with exactly two words on its tape in the form Bw1Bw2B}.
B = Blank Position

the problem of deciding whether an arbitrary Turing machine will accept an arbitrary input, is undecidable. Use this result to prove, formally using problem reduction, that given an arbitrary Turing machine M, the problem of deciding if M ∈ L is undecidable.
............
I have no knowledge of proofs. I don't have a clue how to tackle this question, can someone point me to a tutorial that works with proofs by reduction along with Turing machines.

Comment: [First](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2009/Handouts/reductions/index.html) and [Second](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2009/Handouts/reductions/more-examples.html) links from google

Comment: If you have no knowledge of proofs, computability theory is not the perfect place to start.